# Persistance Layer between Data and Business layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, architecture

For a school project i have to make a movie streaming platform, i decided to develop this with the .net core MVC framework.

Currently my layered architecture looks like this:

- **User Interface Layer (MVC)**
- **Business Layer:**

  - IMove.cs
  - Movie.cs
  - IMovieCollection.cs
  - MovieCollection.cs
- **Contract Layer (For my DTO)**
- **Data Layer**

  - IMovieRepository.cs
  - MovieRepository.cs

The `MovieRepository.cs` contains all my CRUD operations, so in this class i am getting all the movies with  the `GetAll()` method and this is where my problem comes into play. Since i cannot have a reference from my `Business Layer` to my `Data Layer` because this will cause a circular dependency, there is no way i can get the list with movies that my `GetAll()` method returns. I am still pretty new to the multi-tier architecture so i do not really know if its good practice to add another layer between my `Business Layer` and `Data Layer` where i put my repositories with my CRUD operations. Maybe a Persistance Layer?

I hope someone can tell me what the best way is to fix this problem and why.

Comment: Unless you're developing something 10 years ago, there's almost no good reason to use that outdated n-tiered architecture. Just switch to the CLEAN architecture, for your own good.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto could you give an example or link to see what CLEAN architecture is?  It sounds very tempting.Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Just google "asp.net core clean architecture" to find many many examples. If you want a really good book (IMHO, of course), to read on your own time, take a look at Microsoft's ASP.NET Core reference ebook (free): https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/e-book/aspnet/pdf

Comment: The data layer is only responsible for processing data interaction (interaction with the database). The business layer should be responsible for processing the business logic and transactions of the application, providing interfaces for interacting with other layers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Other comments are suggesting to switch to the 'CLEAN architecture'. While these remarks are valid on their own, you mentioned it's for a school project. Because of this I would suggest to focus on 'the basics' and only moving on when you have a good understanding of how everything works. When you have that foundation, you might even figure out the shortcoming of such a setup on your own!

To answer your question: Yes, a common practice is to extract your entities to a separate project that can be referenced by your Business layer and your Data layer. Naming is never an exact science but often this new layer is referred to as the Domain layer.

Comment: And this 'Domain layer' will contain all my repositories with the CRUD operations?

Comment: @acesteef No, you should keep your repositories in the Data Layer. Only your entities should be moved to the Domain layer. In your case that would be the Movie.

Comment: I do not really understand what the difference between the domain layer and my business layer is. What should be put in my business layer if i move all my entities to my domain layer? @ThomasDucheyne